# zooming effects for an image using silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

i am new to silverlight.
i need to create zoom in & zoom out options for an image at run time using silverlight.
please give some idea.
it is better if you explain with some code samples.

Answer (score 1):

Add a ScaleTransform to your image or its container and control the ScaleX and ScaleY properties via some other input mechanism at runtime (typically a Slider control updating the scale values on the its changed event).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Deep Zoom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645) technology.

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout vectorlight toolkit. It has out of box controls for Zoom, Pan, Magnifier features. Check [Vectorlight.net](http://Vectorlight.net) site.